# Stringifying JSON that contains <script> tags

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm trying to pass initial state from server to client by stringifying that state and storing it in global variable. Below is simplified version of what I'm doing.

```
// home.tsx
res.render('home', { appState: {script: '<script></script>'} });

// home.pug
doctype html
html
    head
        script.
            window.__initialState__ = !{JSON.stringify(appState)};
    body
        #root
```

Sadly the result looks like this

```
<script>window.__initialState__ = {"script":"<script></script>
```

which is not valid Javascript. My endgoal is to have server's appState object assigned to window.__initialState__.

Comment: I'm confused. What the first part of your code? Is that supposed to be HTML? Is it generated by server code?

Answer (score 1):

The 1st part of your code is very confusing. However, as a general rule, you should always encode any HTML passed from the server to the client as string.

So you need to change the part of your server code that generated the line below:

```
let scriptObject = {script: '<script></script>'};
```

to this (assuming that you're using pug and node.js):

```
var htmlencode = require('htmlencode');
let scriptObject = {script: htmlencode.htmlEncode('<script></script>')};
```

Comment: I updated the question. I tried encoding it but then `__initialState__.script` doesn't equals `'<script></script>'`. I'd have to loop through all properties of `__initialState__` and unescape them before I can use them.